# Generating static docs with springfox, swagger and gradle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I've evaluated the integration of `springfox` in a simple Spring Boot app exposing few REST API-s. Everything works fine at a first glance - when the application starts I can see the Swagger spec at the JSON endpoint, I can connect and play around with the Swagger UI, Swagger annotations are taken into account, I can generate static HTML docs with the code gen, etc, etc, etc.

What I wonder now is something really simple: how to generate static docs during the build process? I use gradle. During the build the server is apparently down and the JSON endpoint where the swagger spec is is simply not available...

E.g.: `code base -> build -> (executable jar + documentation + ... )`

Answer (score 1):

I had to generate `swagger.json` files at build time to take care of API versioning to work properly when passing the version in the `Accept` header. Did so using `Maven` though but I guess it can help you as a starting point. FYI, I have done it to document APIs using `Spring Boot`, `Jersey` and `Swagger` and `Spring Boot`, `CXF` and `Swagger` instead of `Spring MVC`, `Swagger` and `springfox`.

Using this plugin might also work for you:

```
<properties>
    <swagger-maven-plugin.version>3.1.3</swagger-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>
 ...
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${swagger-maven-plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <apiSources>
      <!-- Version 1 -->
      <apiSource>
        <springmvc>false</springmvc>
        <locations>com.asimio.swaggerexample.rest.v1</locations>
        <schemes>http,https</schemes>
        <basePath>/api</basePath>
        <info>
          <title>Multiversion Spring Boot + Jersey + Swagger Demo (Version 1)</title>
          <version>v1</version>
          <description>A multi-version demo (version 1) of a RESTful service using Spring Boot, Jersey and Swagger.</description>
          <termsOfService>http://www.github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin</termsOfService>
          <contact>
            <email>xxxx@xxxx.xxx</email>
            <name>Orlando L Otero</name>
            <url>http://tech.asimio.net</url>
          </contact>
          <license>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
            <name>Apache 2.0</name>
          </license>
        </info>
        <outputFormats>json</outputFormats>
        <swaggerDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static/v1</swaggerDirectory>
        <swaggerApiReader>com.github.kongchen.swagger.docgen.reader.JaxrsReader</swaggerApiReader>
      </apiSource>
      <!-- Version 2 -->
...
```

More details could be found at: [Documenting multiple REST API versions using Spring Boot, Jersey and Swagger](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/05/07/Documenting-multiple-REST-API-versions-using-Spring-Boot-Jersey-and-Swagger.html)

Comment: pffff... okay. Seems that it will be a long way. I'll try out some ideas and gradle plugins theses days....